# Subclass toString printing null? (using the same parameters for different toStrings)

Tags: java, inheritance, null, tostring

I'm trying to make a mad libs game where the user would input 5 variables (noun, adjective, verb, adverb, 2nd noun) which would then get used throughout my subclasses for different "libs". The problem is that when I input my parameters it prints them out as null. I'm sure there's a simple way to use the same inputs for different toStrings, but I'm new to inheritance and am not sure how that part of it works.

(I looked at other toString null problems, but none of them quite worked with my situation, or there were things wrong with their constructors. I'm fairly certain there's nothing wrong with mine.)

Here is my Phrase superclass:

```
public class Phrase 
{
    private String noun;
    private String adjective;
    private String verb;
    private String adverb;
    private String noun2;

    public Phrase (String n, String a, String v, String ad, String n2)
    {
        n=noun;
        a=adjective;
        v=verb;
        ad=adverb;
        n2=noun2;
    }

    public String getNoun()
    {return noun;}

    public String getAdj ()
    {return adjective;}

    public String getVerb ()
    {return verb;}

    public String getAdverb ()
    {return adverb;}

    public String get2Noun ()
    {return noun2;}

    //i'll need the get methods in the libs classes and the set methods in the 
    while loop, if user wants to change parameters

    public void setNoun (String Newnoun)
    {noun=Newnoun;}

    public void setAdj (String newAdj)
    {adjective=newAdj;}

    public void setVerb (String newVrb)
    {verb=newVrb;}

    public void setAdverb (String newAdv)
    {adverb=newAdv;}

    public void set2Noun (String newNoun2)
    {noun2=newNoun2;}

}
```

Here is my subclass:

```
public class Obama extends Phrase
{
    public Obama(String noun, String adjective, String verb, String adverb, 
            String noun2)
    {super (noun, adjective, verb, adverb, noun2);}

    public String getNoun()
    {return super.getNoun();}

    public String getAdj ()
    {return super.getAdj();}

    public String getVerb ()
    {return super.getVerb();}

    public String getAdverb ()
    {return super.getAdverb();}

    public String get2Noun (String n)
    {return super.get2Noun();}


    public String toString()
    {
        return ("there is a " + super.getAdj() + " " + super.getNoun() +" on the 
                floor! It is " + super.getVerb() +"ing " + super.getAdverb() +". Next to it 
                is a " + super.get2Noun()); 
    }


}
```

Here is my driver:

```
public class Madlibsdriver 
{
    static Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.print ("Welcome to Mad libs!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------- ");
        System.out.println("Enter a noun:");
        String ip1= scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter an adjective:");
        String ip2= scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Enter a verb:");
        String ip3= scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Enter an adverb (ex: angrily) :");
        String ip4= scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Enter another noun:");
        String ip5= scan.nextLine();

        Phrase obama= new Obama(ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print (obama.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've swapped the parameters in your constructor, you set the values you pass in (instead of using them to set your local fields). Use the `this` keyword to catch this class of errors, like

```
public Phrase (String n, String a, String v, String ad, String n2)
{
    this.noun = n;
    this.adjective = a;
    this.verb = v;
    this.adverb = ad;
    this.noun2 = n2;
}
```